# inner ngOnInit doesn't invoke when I write `ngOnInit` in the parent component

Tags: angular

In my component I extends `FooComponent`. in `FooComponent` I want to do something in `ngOnInit` that every component that extends from it need to do.

But when I defined `ngOnInit` in the parent component, then `ngOnInit` of foo not invoke.

Any idea how to have both `ngOnInit` in the `FooComponent` and in the `AppComponent` and invoke the `ngOnInit` in `FooComponent` and `ngOnInit` in `AppComponent`?

**Please note**:
I don't want to use and write`super.ngOnInit()` every time I implement `ngOnInit` in every component.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kkdgzx)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({ template: "" })
export abstract class FooComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("foo ngOnInit");
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `
    <h1>app works</h1>
  `
})
export class AppComponent extends FooComponent {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("in ngOnInit");
  }
}
```

Comment: if you write `ngOnInit` in AppComponent, you "override" the ngOnInit of the FooComponent, if you remove it you should see "foo ngOnInit" in console

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the consturctor, `ngOnInit` is a lifecycle hook that will be triggered only when the component is being rendered by the rendering engine. You could instead explicitly call the parent's `ngOnInit` function.

```js
export class AppComponent extends FooComponent {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("in ngOnInit");
    super.ngOnInit();
  }
}
```

Comment: can't do it. I looking for simple solution without using super. somebody else see my code and may not understand why it not works until it inspect the `FooComponent` and read the code.

Comment: It can't be done. Angular components are not regular Typescript classes. Each component constitute an individual entity that are treated separately by Angular. If you wish to run something in the base "class", then it should be in the constructor.

Comment: Also these are Frontend codes. Even with obfuscation, the codes could be reversed and read by anyone who uses them.

Answer (score 0):

AppComponent is inheriting from FooComponent so when you add the ngOnInit function to AppComponent you are overwriting the ngOnInit on FooComponent.

I would suggest adding an init method to FooComponent and calling it from AppComponent.  You can also call it from ngOnInit in FooComponent if that component is likely to be used separately

```
...
FooComponent implements OnInit {

    protected init() {
        console.log('Foo init');
    }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.init();
    }
}

...
AppComponent extends FooComponent implements OnInit {

    ngOnInit() {
      this.init();
    }
}
```